# Lagrangian with derivative of the field in the denominator

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, action

I stumbled upon this strange Lagrangian today (euclidian, in 2D),

$$
\mathcal{A} ~=~ \iint d^{2}\vec{x}\left( \partial_i\phi  \,\partial^i \phi \; + \;g\, \frac{(\partial^i \phi) \, (\partial_{i} \partial_j \phi) \, (\partial^j \phi)}{(\partial_k \phi)(\partial^k \phi)}  \right) 
$$
Where $g$ is a constant.

It appears relatively naturally in a conformally invariant polymer model.

Does it appear somewhere else? Any hope of re-expressing it in a more amenable form? Does it even mean something?

Comment: Can you do something with a surface term? Just flailing. What happens at the limits of $x$?  Maybe that needs more. Can you move that $\partial_i $ over onto the $\partial^i \phi $ and then cancel the wacky term?

Comment: No boundary, but I don't know if the term is a total derivative

Comment: Usually when I see fields in the denominator, it means that I should expand around a background (e.g. f(R) Gravity). Are you in such kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the post (v2):

1. OP's Lagrangian density is 
   $$ {\cal L}_1~\sim~(\partial\phi)^2 -\frac{g}{2}    \ln (\partial\phi)^2~\Box\phi \tag{1}$$
   up to total spacetime derivative terms.
2. The extended Lagrangian density
   $$ {\cal L}_2~=~e^{\Phi} (1-B) +B(\partial\phi)^2 -\frac{g}{2}\Phi~\Box\phi \quad \stackrel{\text{int. out } B, \Phi}{\longrightarrow}\quad{\cal L}_1 \tag{2}$$
   becomes ${\cal L}_1$ if we integrate out the Lagrange multiplier $B$, because this would enforce the constraint 
   $$e^{\Phi}~\approx~ (\partial\phi)^2.\tag{3}$$